# Не работает DNS kubernetes внутри контейнеров

Tags: linux, docker, centos, kubernetes

Нет резолва внутри docker-контейнеров на кластере Kubernetes. На физической машине все ок.

Сам конфиг coredns виглядит так:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          upstream
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        proxy . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
```

В логах пода coredns ошибок нет.

Внутри контейнера файл /etc/resolv.conf выглядит:

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Не могу понять почему внутри контейнеров не работает dns. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была подобная проблема. Дня три искал. Виноват был `firewald`. В него похоже добавили функции `hosts.allow`, `hosts.deny` или вроде того. Но сильно не копал. Попробуй так:

`systemctl mask firewald`

и перезагрузись, чтоб отключить его совсем. Также посмотри `apparmor` или `selinux`.

Что интересно при этом в `iptables-save` нет никаких блокировок. Разрешить работу приложений получилось через `firewall-applet` - включил нужные службы. Где находится конфигурация в файлах пока не нашел.

Также firewald блокирует dhcp и tftp.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Проблема была в firewalld.